# How to set html Div aside and under each other using css Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to apply the below concept using `Flexbox`. It is easy to do it using bootstrap grid system.

[image]

Below is the html code

```
<div class="bottom-pane">
    <div class="chiller equipment">1</div>
    <div class="vacuum-system equipment">2</div>
    <div class="compressed-air equipment">3</div>
    <div class="dust-collection equipment">4</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.bottom-pane{
    display: flex;
}
.bottom-pane .equipment{
    border: solid red 1px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

My code are setting the `Divs` all aside each other even if I set the `width` to 50%, the below image is the result of my code

[image]

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I assumed my code should give result the same as the first image, but getting them all in the same row. (see second image) @koder613

Comment: You need to add flex-wrap:wrap

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how I think it should work aswell, but however in this case you need to define flex-wrap. This is because the default value for flex-wrap is nowrap:

> Nowrap: All flex items will be on one line.

For more details you can read [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.bottom-pane{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.bottom-pane .equipment{
    border: solid red 1px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="bottom-pane">
        <div class="chiller equipment">1</div>
        <div class="vacuum-system equipment">2</div>
        <div class="compressed-air equipment">3</div>
        <div class="dust-collection equipment">4</div>
    </div>
```